# Can you use `fromIntegral` to solve this type error?

Tags: haskell, types, typeerror

Would using `fromIntegral` help fix this type error I'm getting.

> `Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’ with actual type ‘Int’`?

If not, how can I resolve it?

```hs
taxiFare :: Int -> Float  
taxiFare x | x >= 10 = longRide
           | otherwise = shortRide
           where
               longRide  = 2.2 + (x * 0.3) + 2
               shortRide = 2.2 + (x * 0.5)
```

Comment: The type signature seems overly restrictive (no 3.5km trips?) If you omit it entirely, a type of `(Ord p, Fractional p) => p -> p` is inferred. (The fractional constraint comes from the fact that your constants all have type `Fractional p => p`, rather than the more general `Num a => a` type of "integer" constants like 10.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your signature specifies that `x` is an `Int`. But the result type should be a `Float` since calculations like [`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-) and [`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) require the two operands and the result to be all of the same type, it thus means that `x` should be a `Float`.

You can make use of [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert any `Integral` type to any `Num` type, so **yes**. You can define for example a variable that will store the `Float` counterpart of `x` and use that variable:

```
taxiFare :: Int -> Float  
taxiFare x
    | x >= 10 = longRide
    | otherwise = shortRide
    where longRide  = 0.3 * xf + 4.2
          shortRide = 0.5 * xf + 2.2
          xf = fromIntegral x
```